# Push-notifications and MVVMCross

Tags: c#, push-notification, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

We are facing a problem with handling a notification on Android with MVVMCross.

I implemented the default `void CreateNotification()` but when we tap the notification in the notification center, the `onCreate()` fails with the following exception:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object

The code we are using:

```
var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);

//Create an intent to show ui
var uiIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(HomeView));

var notification = new Notification(Android.Resource.Drawable.StarOn, title);
notification.Flags = NotificationFlags.AutoCancel;

notification.SetLatestEventInfo(this, title, desc, PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, uiIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent));

notificationManager.Notify(1, notification);
```

The HomeView in this sample is of type:

> public abstract class MvxBindingActivityView :
>   Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxActivityView
>               where TViewModel : class, Cirrious.MvvmCross.Interfaces.ViewModels.IMvxViewModel
>       Member of Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views

Can anybody help us where to fix this problem?

Thanks,
Christian

Answer (score 1):

Providing a NullReference exception without any trace or call stack info is asking for 'long shot' guesses... Please try to provide something more if you can - eg by catching the exception and tracing the CallStack and/or by looking at the output window or monitor.bat trace.

With that said, I like long shots... and I suspect your problem is in the way you are showing the activity - to show an mvxactivity you need to provide a serialised MvxVieWModleRequest in your Intent Extras - the easiest way to do this is use the ShowViewModel API on an MvxNavigatingObject (MvxApplicationObject in vNext). Alternatively you can use the object that implements `https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/vnext/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid/Interfaces/IMvxAndroidViewModelRequestTranslator.cs` - you can get this using IoC

I hope that guess is right - if not, then stack trace and log output please :)

Stuart

Comment: You took a right guess about my problem. As you said, we didn't use a MvxViewModelRequest. While trying this right now, we see that this works perfectly when the app is already running! Only when the device is rebooted and the app isn't started, the call 'CreateIntentFor<>' crashed with a nullreference error. Do you need the stack trace for this or do you like this long shot?

Comment: > 'Do you need the stack trace for this?' - sounds like *you* should do some work and some investigation. Why don't you take a look at it and try debugging it?